# Setting a dynamic date format in Elastic Search

Tags: java, sorting, datetime, elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search.

I have a User mapping and associated with the User is a Nested Object `extraDataValues`. In this object is the id, a string value and another nested object. For example:

```
"extraDataValues": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "01/01/2016 00:00:00",
        "id": 10,
            "label": "Metadata Date",
            "displayable": true
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "aaaa",
        "id": 11,
            "label": "Metadata TextBox",
            "displayable": true
        },
    }
],
```

As you can see, value field can be a date or a normal string. The problem arises here, I want to be able to sort this value given that it could be either a date or a normal string. Moreover, the date can be in two formats: `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy"`. How can I achieve this firstly with Elastic Search (so I can understand the theory) and then Java?

I have tried adding `"dynamic_date_formats" : ["dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy"]`
 to no avail.

The mapping for the Users is:

```
    User Mapping Document
{
    "User": {
       "properties": {
            "fullName": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },              
            "username": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "email": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "firstName": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "surname": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "extraDataValues": {
                "type": "nested",
                "dynamic_date_formats" : ["dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy"],
                "properties": {
                    "extraDataValueObject": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "displayable": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index":    "not_analyzed",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw_lower_case": { 
                                "type":  "string",
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that the way you are trying to do it. `dynamic_date_formats` are used only for dynamically added date fields, not for date fields that you specify in your mapping (from [the documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_date_formats)).

What I would suggest trying out is this mapping:

```
   "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "date1": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
          "ignore_malformed": "true"
        },
        "date2": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dd/MM/yyyy",
          "ignore_malformed": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

Where you have a field which is `string` (for the string type part of the value) and for it you define two subfields each with a different date format. It's imperative to have for them `"ignore_malformed": "true"` in case you really have a `string` instead of a date coming in.

In this way you can index this:

```
POST /my_index/user/1
{
  "value": "aaa"
}
POST /my_index/user/2
{
  "value": "01/01/2016 00:00:00"
}
POST /my_index/user/3
{
  "value": "02/02/2016"
}
```

And you could differentiate between which type of date or string was indexed like this in a query:

```
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "value.date2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If ES was able to index something under `value.date2` then you get that document back. The same goes for `value.date1`, of course.